# Modify Java code to support both AES128 and AES256

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I have found the code of AES encryption and decryption on git hub as bellow:

```
public static String encrypt(String plainText, String key) throws Exception {
    byte[] clean = plainText.getBytes();

    // Generating IV.
        int ivSize = 16;
        byte[] iv = new byte[ivSize];
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        random.nextBytes(iv);
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    // Hashing key.
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        digest.update(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(digest.digest(), 0, keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

    // Encrypt.
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clean);

    // Combine IV and encrypted part.
        byte[] encryptedIVAndText = new byte[ivSize + encrypted.length];
        System.arraycopy(iv, 0, encryptedIVAndText, 0, ivSize);
        System.arraycopy(encrypted, 0, encryptedIVAndText, ivSize, encrypted.length);

    return new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(encryptedIVAndText));
}

// decrypt method
public static String decrypt(String encrypted, String key) throws Exception {
    int ivSize = 16;
    int keySize = 16;

    byte[] encryptedIvTextBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypted);
    // Extract IV.
        byte[] iv = new byte[ivSize];
        System.arraycopy(encryptedIvTextBytes, 0, iv, 0, iv.length);
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    // Extract encrypted part.
        int encryptedSize = encryptedIvTextBytes.length - ivSize;
        byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[encryptedSize];
        System.arraycopy(encryptedIvTextBytes, ivSize, encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedSize);

    // Hash key.
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[keySize];
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(key.getBytes());
        System.arraycopy(md.digest(), 0, keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

    // Decrypt.
        Cipher cipherDecrypt = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipherDecrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipherDecrypt.doFinal(encryptedBytes);

    return new String(decrypted);
}
```

I've found the information that java determine aes algorithm 128 or 256 by key size, so I have modify the code above by changing fixed value of "keySize" to  key.length() as bellow:

```
public static String encryptAes(String plainText, String key){
    byte[] clean = plainText.getBytes();
    String str = null;
    int keyLen = key.length();

    try{
        // Generating IV.
        int ivSize = 16;
        byte[] iv = new byte[ivSize];
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        random.nextBytes(iv);
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    // Hashing key.
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        digest.update(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[keyLen];
        System.arraycopy(digest.digest(), 0, keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

    // Encrypt.
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clean);

    // Combine IV and encrypted part.
        byte[] encryptedIVAndText = new byte[ivSize + encrypted.length];
        System.arraycopy(iv, 0, encryptedIVAndText, 0, ivSize);
        System.arraycopy(encrypted, 0, encryptedIVAndText, ivSize, encrypted.length);
        str = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(encryptedIVAndText));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
    return str;
}

public static String decryptAes(String encrypted, String key){
    int ivSize = 16;
    int keySize = key.length();
    String str = null;

    try{
        byte[] encryptedIvTextBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypted);
        // Extract IV.
        byte[] iv = new byte[ivSize];
        System.arraycopy(encryptedIvTextBytes, 0, iv, 0, iv.length);
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    // Extract encrypted part.
        int encryptedSize = encryptedIvTextBytes.length - ivSize;
        byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[encryptedSize];
        System.arraycopy(encryptedIvTextBytes, ivSize, encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedSize);

    // Hash key.
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[keySize];
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(key.getBytes());
        System.arraycopy(md.digest(), 0, keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

    // Decrypt.
        Cipher cipherDecrypt = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipherDecrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipherDecrypt.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
    
        str = new String(decrypted);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
    return str;
}
```

And here is Main with and input

```
public static void main (String[] args){

    String txtInput = "11700000108";

    String key256 = "SxKFF2Kunz7tjyUZ4sb7TzzZBR83e8FL"; //length of key will be fixed as 32
    String cipher256 = encryptAes(txtInput, key256);
    System.out.println("CipherAes256: " + cipher256);

    String key128 = "RfZVnF76FshjN46e"; //length of key will be fixed as 16
    String cipher128 = encryptAes(txtInput, key128);
    System.out.println("CipherAes128: " + cipher128);
}
```

But the result's length of cipher256 and cipher128 are same (44 characters in this example) I'm not sure if I need to make any further changes.
Please give me advice, Thanks.

Comment: Changing the AES variant does not affect the size of the ciphertext, so that is no issue here. However, the original code seems to derive a key from a password. Your change causes the size of the password to match the desired key size, so it would be better to use an additional parameter for the key size to make the key size independent of the password.

Comment: Note that a digest as key derivation is insecure, for this there are dedicated methods like PBKDF2. Also, you should always specify a charset (e.g. UTF-8) in `getBytes()` or `new String(...)`.